# Can I get this result in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table1 with

[image]

Is-it possible to have table2:

[image]

Comment: I have in the column1 2 times the same attribute and i want to have it only one time.. I do not know if that can help to find the solution.. sorry..

Comment: OUPS.. The first table table1 have only 2 column (column1 and column1 2) and I want to create the second table.. I have no rule for that.. I got the table1 and I want create the table2. Thanks anyway even there is no solution

Comment: try first, ask before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution that comes to mind involves subquery and `row_number` analytic function:

```
select
  column1,
  max(case when rn = 1 then column2 end) as column2,
  max(case when rn = 2 then column2 end) as column3
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by column1 order by column2) as rn
  from table1
  ) t
group by column1
```

Or you could simply use `min` and `max` rule like below, but I like the first one better:

```
select
  column1,
  min(column2) as column2,
  max(column2) as column3
from table1
group by column1
```